# How to make a field appear only if a post meta field has a defined value?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I have a post meta field `registrazione_singolaono`that has 2 value:

```
singolo_file
piu_file
```

If one of these value is selected (in every post the first or the latter must be used) i want to show another custom meta field.

For example: if the value of the custom meta field is

> singolo_file

It should display:

```
<?php  if((get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'registrazione_multipla', true))) { ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'registrazione_multipla', true ); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

If it is:

```
piu_file
```

it should display another big piece of php functions.
I searched both on the codex, on this site and on google without getting any understandable help.
Thanks. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the meta value in a variable, and use an if/elseif statement to determine what should be displayed, like so:

```
$registrazione_singolaono = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'registrazione_singolaono', true );
$registrazione_multipla = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'registrazione_multipla', true );

if ( 'singolo_file' == $registrazione_singolaono && ! empty( $registrazione_multipla ) ) {
    echo $registrazione_multipla;
} elseif ( 'piu_file' == $registrazione_multipla ) {
    // something else
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code

Comment: @PieterGoosen Done

Comment: @NateAllen your code is not working, but i am trying to adapt it. Firstly i think that the first line should be $registrazione_singolaonothat and not $registrazione multipla, that is another field that will be visualized only if the value of registrazione_singolaonothat is singolo_file

Comment: @Benjamin Ok, I updated the code. I also added a check to make sure the $registrazione_multipla wasn't empty before echoing it.

Comment: I put the code between <?php and ?> and it doesn't work. I am i doing something wrong? It doesn't display anything @NateAllen

Comment: @NateAllen modifying your code i came to the solution. Thank you very much.